# EJS template engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm doing a node.js project and I've an ejs template file which further uses templates for header and footer.

**template.ejs looks like this:**

```
<%- include(header) %>
main html body
<%- include(footer) %>

<script type='text/javascript'>
...
...
...
</script>
```

when I run the server, the script embedded between the **script** tags becomes clearly visible. How do I hide this part from the page rendered by the node server.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot do this in EJS (I may be wrong), so you should include the script as an asset and load it from the HTML.

```html
<script src="path/to/script"></script>
```